# Did "slave" ever apply to anything other than people?

Tags: etymology

Modern use of slave has evolved to include electronic devices in a "master / slave" configuration.

Did this use of "slave" ever exist before electronic devices used it? Did the word "slave" ever apply to things other than humans?

Comment: While still *generally* talking about humans, you can also enslave the mind/soul/will.

Comment: I've had to replace the "slave cylinder" in multiple hydraulic systems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The collocation (and meaning) *slave device* goes back well before electronic devices. The OED gives examples of meaning C1 c. ("Used to denote a subsidiary device, esp. one which is controlled by, or which follows accurately the movements of, another device.") from 1904.

Comment: +1, but the characterization of 1904 as "well before electronic devices" is [rather dubious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_electric_vehicle) (unless by *electronic* you mean *has integrated circuits*).

Comment: I have accepted this answer because you've understood what I was trying to say and provided a useful link. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterShor -- I think you are confusing `electronic` with `electric`.

Comment: @PeterShor: The citation from 1904 is " The Clock consists of two separate instruments:—(a) A pendulum... (b) The ‘slave-clock’ with a wheel train and dead-beat escapement, the pendulum of which has a period of vibration slightly shorter than one second." While this does not explicitly say it was not electric, I think it is pretty clear that it was not. This is leaving aside Malvolio's point, which is relevant.

Comment: @PeterShor: For a few minutes I couldn't believe your name was actually Peter Shor... I thought it was someone else pretending to have the same name as you haha.

Answer (score 10):

Ants take slaves:

> [Slave-making ants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave-making_ant) are brood parasites that capture brood of other ant species to increase the worker force of their colony. After emerging in the slave-maker nest, slave workers work as if they were in their own colony, while parasite workers only concentrate on replenishing the labor force from neighboring host nests, a process called *slave raiding*.

You can argue that cuckoos enslave other birds to raise their young as well.

Answer (score 3):

OED lists “slave jib” or just “slave” as a sailing term from 1934, meaning a jib that was pretty much permanently set.